# Generate task based WCF service references with svcutil

Tags: .net, wcf, task, svcutil.exe

I read an article recently regarding creating task based WCF service references in [this article](http://www.devcurry.com/2012/12/task-based-wcf-services-in-net-45.html).

The mechanism that I use to generate my service references for consuming applications is using svcutil in a batch file.

Is it possible to create task based wcf service references with svcutil?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't tried it yet, but it looks like version 4.5 of svcutil.exe includes Task-Based operations by default.  You can use the "/syncOnly" flag to disable Task-Based operations.  [Source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/endpoint/archive/2010/11/13/simplified-asynchronous-programming-model-in-wcf-with-async-await.aspx)

Also, if you want to include task-based operations within Visual Studio, you can select that option when importing the web service.  [Source](http://www.devcurry.com/2012/12/task-based-wcf-services-in-net-45.html)

Answer (score 2):

Add the switch `/tcv:version35`. It will generate the task based operation by default (provided you should not specify `/synconly` switch).